# How to Insert values in a Twig template and use the plain text as a string?

Tags: php, twig, slim

I want to be able to send html email. I created the template with twig and I have some variables in it `{{ name }} {{ date }}` and so on.
What I want to do now is to pass variables from my php script into the template and to use the new html file with the injected values as a string which I am going to `mail()`. 
How could I achieve this ?
I tried

```
  $emailText = $this->container['view']->render('user/mailTemplate.html', array('name' => $username, 'date'=>$currentdate));
```

> But I get 'Message: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Views\Twig::render()
>   must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface '

Comment: the first arguments must be the $response object of your route method. Check [Figure 5 in the doc here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html)

Comment: ok,but how about if I do not have a resposne object ...all I want to do is to tell twig to render the template with my values ,but not to give me back the template as a response object.?

Comment: the library you are using is about [rendering PHP view scripts into a PSR-7 Response object](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#usage-with-any-psr-7-project). The only think you can do is about [using a new response object](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#usage-with-any-psr-7-project)

Comment: Are you using Slim framework?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Slim Framework Twig View](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) component gives you the `fetchFromString()` method:

```
$rendered = $this->view->fetchFromString(
    $template_string, 
    array('fname' => 'John',
        'lname' => 'Doe')
);
```

Or use `->fetch()` to load the template from a file (if it is in the template directory).